# Container command fails in Django on Elastic Beanstalk Python 3.7

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using Django Python 3.7 on Elastic Beanstalk (Amazon Linux 2) and the following command fails:

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "pipenv run python ./manage.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
```

```
2020-07-17 09:31:57,017 [ERROR] Command 01_migrate (pipenv run python ./manage.py migrate) failed
2020-07-17 09:31:57,017 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of postbuild_0_sarahandanatol: Command 01_migrate failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 542, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 260, in build
    changes['commands'] = CommandTool().apply(self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 117, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
ToolError: Command 01_migrate failed
```

Comment: Hi. On AL2, if you want to execute your code under python 3, I think it should be `python3`. Have you tried with `python3`?

Comment: not yet but going to now! :-)

Comment: @Marcin I get the same error with this container command: `pipenv run python3 ./manage.py migrate` and for some reason, the exception still shows it is using python 2.7

Comment: So this was working on AL1, but now when you migrate to AL2 it stopped working?

Comment: @Marcin the command worked on AL1: `python ./manage.py migrate` but `pipenv run python3 ./manage.py migrate` doesn't work on AL2

Comment: can you check `/var/log/cfn-init-cmd.log`? Maybe it has more useful error message?

Comment: @Marcin yep you were right! `Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?` I have django installed though and I run `pipenv run` before the commands?

Comment: Well that's the root of the issue. That's good it got established.  Have you tried without `pipenv run`?

Comment: @Marcin Tried just now like this `python3 ./manage.py migrate`. still the same issue

Comment: Are you sure django is installed? when you login to the instance does your application work?

Comment: I have Django listed in my Pipfile. The instance has a sample app because my app couldn't be deployed because it will fail on the migrate command

Comment: You are not using `requirements.txt` file?

Comment: @Marcin no. I am using pipenv. that's why I was running `pipenv run` before the migrate command

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218030/discussion-between-marcin-and-anatol).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried to **replicate the issue** on my sandbox account. It was minimal version of the django
just with the welcome screen. No database nor the use of environmental variables.

My `Pipfile` was minimal as well:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
django = "*"
djangorestframework = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"
```

I can **confirm that using plain pipenv fails**. Specifically, I had the following config file
in my `.ebextantions`

```
container_commands:
  10_migrate:
    command: |
      pipenv run python ./manage.py migrate
```

The error message was about **missing Django**.

However, for me the **solution** was the following:

```
container_commands:
  10_migrate:
    command: |      
      source $PYTHONPATH/activate
      pipenv run python ./manage.py migrate
```

This activates python environment that EB is using to install Pipfile dependencies
before pipenv is executed.

Below is a version which will also load EB environmental variables that maybe
required to run the migrate job if you have database connection details
passed as such.

```
container_commands:
  10_migrate:
    command: |
      export $(cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env | xargs)
      source $PYTHONPATH/activate
      pipenv run python ./manage.py migrate
```

Here is an example output from `/var/log/cfn-init-cmd.log` showing successful migrate run:

```
20-07-18 04:50:41,615 P3836 [INFO] Command 10_migrate
2020-07-18 04:50:42,969 P3836 [INFO] -----------------------Command Output-----------------------
2020-07-18 04:50:42,969 P3836 [INFO]    cat: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env: No such file or directory
2020-07-18 04:50:42,969 P3836 [INFO]    export EB_IS_COMMAND_LEADER="true"
2020-07-18 04:50:42,969 P3836 [INFO]    export HOME="/root"
2020-07-18 04:50:42,969 P3836 [INFO]    export MYVAR="my-eb-env-value"
2020-07-18 04:50:42,969 P3836 [INFO]    export OLDPWD
2020-07-18 04:50:42,970 P3836 [INFO]    export PATH="/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin"
2020-07-18 04:50:42,970 P3836 [INFO]    export PWD="/var/app/staging"
2020-07-18 04:50:42,970 P3836 [INFO]    export PYTHONPATH="/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin"
2020-07-18 04:50:42,970 P3836 [INFO]    export SHLVL="4"
2020-07-18 04:50:42,970 P3836 [INFO]    export _="/bin/jq"
2020-07-18 04:50:42,970 P3836 [INFO]    Courtesy Notice: Pipenv found itself running within a virtual environment, so it will automatically use that environment, instead of creating its own for any project. You can set PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1 to force pipenv to ignore that environment and create its own instead. You can set PIPENV_VERBOSITY=-1 to suppress this warning.
2020-07-18 04:50:42,970 P3836 [INFO]    Operations to perform:
2020-07-18 04:50:42,970 P3836 [INFO]      Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
2020-07-18 04:50:42,970 P3836 [INFO]    Running migrations:
2020-07-18 04:50:42,970 P3836 [INFO]      Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
2020-07-18 04:50:42,970 P3836 [INFO]      Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
2020-07-18 04:50:42,970 P3836 [INFO]      Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
2020-07-18 04:50:42,970 P3836 [INFO]      Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
2020-07-18 04:50:42,970 P3836 [INFO]      Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
2020-07-18 04:50:42,971 P3836 [INFO]      Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
2020-07-18 04:50:42,971 P3836 [INFO]      Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
2020-07-18 04:50:42,971 P3836 [INFO]      Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
2020-07-18 04:50:42,971 P3836 [INFO]      Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
2020-07-18 04:50:42,971 P3836 [INFO]      Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
2020-07-18 04:50:42,971 P3836 [INFO]      Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
2020-07-18 04:50:42,971 P3836 [INFO]      Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
2020-07-18 04:50:42,971 P3836 [INFO]      Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
2020-07-18 04:50:42,971 P3836 [INFO]      Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
2020-07-18 04:50:42,971 P3836 [INFO]      Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
2020-07-18 04:50:42,971 P3836 [INFO]      Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
2020-07-18 04:50:42,971 P3836 [INFO]      Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
```

Comment: `source $PYTHONPATH/activate` was key for me after several hours of frustration.

Comment: This answer [was plagiarised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73720169/container-commands-fail-to-migrate-django-database/73721485#73721485).

Comment: [Among others](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382697/how-can-i-get-unblocked-from-answering-questions#comment1276489_382697).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Not sure what do you mean? My answer is from 2020. The answer you linked is from 2022.

Comment: I thought you would misunderstand it. That is why I wrote "This answer was plagiarised.". But that was apparently not enough. "This answer" = your answer. *Your* answer was the victim of plagiarism. Or in order words: Somebody plagiarised *your* answer. Somebody copy and pasted your answer. That somebody else is the one that plagiarised. You didn't plagiarise anything. You are not a plagiariser. Somebody else is a plagiariser. I now realise the verb tense and/or passive construction makes a difference, *is* ambiguous, and *can* be misunderstood. My fault. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I should have written *"This answer was plagiarised by somebody else."*, *"This answer was plagiarised in 2022."*, *"Somebody else plagiarised this answer."*, or similar.