# container_commands fail to migrate Django database

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

If I remove the following:

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && python manage.py migrate --no-input"
    leader_only: true
```

The app gets successfully deployed.

When I `eb ssh` and try to run `python manage.py migrate` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 386, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 87, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 74, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 183, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/app/current/dca/dca/settings.py", line 104, in <module>
    'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/os.py", line 675, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'RDS_DB_NAME'
```

I looked at a lot of the answers posted and have tried almost all the solutions given. I still get the same errors.

How could I resolve this?

Comment: Similar (an answer here is a plagiarised version of an answer there): *[Container command fails in Django on Elastic Beanstalk Python 3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62951268/)*

Answer (score 1):

Your error suggests that [EB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWS_Elastic_Beanstalk) is having difficulties with finding your environment variables. **During** deployment, these environment variables are available. When ssh'ing into your instance however, you will have to import them manually. You can find the documentation [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-env-variables-shell/)

One way to do this is to use the [get-config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platforms-scripts.html) tool, which is located at `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config`.

You can use the following command to print your environment variables:

```
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment
```

However, you still need to [export](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/export-command-in-linux-with-examples/) them. This can be done with the following command:

```
export $(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment| xargs)
```

Now Django should be able to find the environment variables as set in your EB environment.

Alternatively, you should also be able to export you environment variables via:

```
export $(cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env | xargs)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to see the environment variables.