# ToolError: Command 01_migrate failed on Amazon LM2

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a webapp made on django to AWS Elastic BeanStalk but it is showing the following error:

> cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Command 01_migrate failed

Traceback:

```
2021-08-04 09:49:56,443 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
2021-08-04 09:49:56,443 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Command 01_migrate failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 176, in <module>
    worklog.build(metadata, configSets)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 135, in build
    Contractor(metadata).build(configSets, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 561, in build
    self.run_config(config, worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 573, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 273, in build
    self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 127, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Command 01_migrate failed
```

db-migrate.config

on LM1 was:

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "django-admin.py migrate --noinput"
    leader_only: true
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: packsapp.settings
```

for LM2 I tried this:

```
container_commands:
    01_migrate:
        command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && python3 manage.py migrate"
        leader_only: true
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: packsapp.settings
```

and also tried this as well

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && django-admin.py migrate --noinput"
    leader_only: true
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: packsapp.settings
```

But it still fails. What do I need to change?

Comment: If you ssh to your EB instance, can you make it work manually? This try can give you some extra insights on what's happening.

Comment: If you SSH into instance and tail `eb-activity.log`, it might have useful information on why migrate has failed.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62457165/deploying-django-to-elastic-beanstalk-migrations-failed/63074781#63074781) help?

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the previous answer, Amazon Linux 2 (AL2) is very different from Amazon Linux 1 (AL1) - to add to the frustration, the AWS docs do not provide an accurate way to conduct migrations. After many hours of digging, here is the approach I found that works:

### Hooks

AL2 introduces [hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) as a method to run shell commands at different stages of deployment. The hook we are looking for is the `postdeploy` hook illustrated below:

First, our directory structure should look something like this:

```sh
my_project
|-- .platform/
|    |-- hooks/              
|        |-- postdeploy/
|            |-- 01_migrate.sh
|-- my_first_app
|-- my_second_app
```

Next, we add the the `01_migrate.sh` script to execute on the leader only:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

source "$PYTHONPATH/activate" && {
    
    if [[ $EB_IS_COMMAND_LEADER == "true" ]];
    then 
        # log which migrations have already been applied
        python manage.py showmigrations;
        
        # migrate
        python manage.py migrate --noinput;
    else 
        echo "this instance is NOT the leader";
    fi
    
}
```

### Logs

If configured correctly, we'll see the migrations printed under the `/var/log/eb-hooks.log` section of the eb logs (i.e. run `eb logs`):

```sh
----------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-hooks.log
----------------------------------------
my_first_app
 [X] 0001_my_first_app_migration_1
 [X] 0002_my_first_app_migration_2
my_second_app
 [X] 0001_my_second_app_migration_1
 [X] 0002_my_second_app_migration_2
```

We can now remove the container command that conducts our migrations.

### Notes

1. you need to add the shell file above to the `postdeploy` hook which, in my opinion, is completely non-intuitive
2. you can add other django commands like `collectstatic` (typically I just include it in the file above)
3. like commands on AL1, the shell script "hooks" are executed in alphabetical order (hence the 01 prefix)

Good luck!

Comment: One gotcha I ran across switching to this approach (and admittedly I don't understand all the moving parts here) was that I needed to explicitly set the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY environment variables in Elastic Beanstalk (my database is in RDS so Django needed those values to connect to the DB). Previously, the container_commands version seems to have those magically injected from the IAM instance profile. I tried using approaches I've found that use `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment` but those values were not included from the output of that script.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Linux 2 has a fundamentally different setup than AL1, and the current documentation as of Jul 24, 2020 is out of date. django-admin of the installed environment by beanstalk does not appear to be on the path, so you can source the environment to activate and make sure it is.

More answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62457165/deploying-django-to-elastic-beanstalk-migrations-failed/63074781#63074781) as well which goes into much more detail in how arrived at this answer, but the solution (which I don't love) is:

```
container_commands:
    01_migrate:
        command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && python3 manage.py migrate"
        leader_only: true
```